# eclipse persists on not ignoring files in a directory which is a symbolic link

Tags: linux, eclipse, cvs, symlink

I have a symbolic link foo to directory baz in my project. Both baz and foo are in the same directory. I added foo to .cvsignore in the parent directory, but eclipse still wants to synchronize the contents of foo (which also has subdirectories), which I can't commit because they are already commited in directory baz.

So it looks like this:

```
$ mkdir baz
$ ln -s baz foo
$ echo "foo" >> .cvsignore
```

So I have a lot of unneeded clutter. How can I tell eclipse to ignore the contents of foo? Please help.